# A recursion with a number-theoretic function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

For a positive integer $Q$, let
  $$ s(Q) := Q\,\sum_{p\mid Q} \frac1p, $$
where the sum extends over all prime divisors of $Q$; also, let $s(0)=0$. Thus, we have, for instance,

- $s(1)=0$, while $s(p^\alpha)=p^{\alpha-1}$ for any prime $p$ and integer 
  $\alpha\ge 1$;
- $s(PQ)=Ps(Q)+Qs(P)$ whenever $P,Q\ge 1$ are coprime;
- if $p\mid Q$, then $\nu_p(s(Q))=\nu_p(Q)-1$, where $\nu_p(Q)$ denotes the $p$-adic valuation of $Q$.

The last property shows that there are no $Q>0$ with $s(Q)=Q$. Do there exist $P,Q>0$ such that $s(P)=Q$ and $s(Q)=P$? This is, in disguise, [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/320838/9924). And, ultimately, a Collatz-type question:

> Is it true that for any $Q_0\ge 0$, the sequence recursively defined by $Q_n=s(Q_{n-1})$ eventually stabilizes at $0$? (I have numerically verified this for all $Q_0\le 10^7$.)

Comment: Let P be the primorial larger than Q, with the largest prime dividing P being p.  S enlarges Q by a multiplicative factor of less than log log p, so it takes r = log p / log log p iterations or more to reach the next primorial after P.  For r large (say r greater than 5), you don't have enough powers in Q to reach that primorial, and when you run out of powers, you decrease by something akin to 1/(p+2).  This argument is far from precise, but the idea is that starting from Q, if you are lucky to reach P with S, you won't get to pP.  Gerhard "Believes In Power Of Loglog" Paseman, 2019.02.14.

Comment: $10^7$ looks too small, since the series of prime reciprocals diverges extremely slowly

Comment: Wouldn't $s(P)=Q$ and $s(Q)=P$ imply $s(s(P))=P$ ? Which would be impossible from the decreasing of the valuation.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: $s(P)=Q$ and $s(Q)=P$ certainly imply $s(s(P))=P$, but the fact that the valuations decrease does not make this impossible, it just shows that $P$ must be square-free.

Comment: But then all the valuations decrease so $s(s(P))=0$.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Positive valuations decrease but null ones can jump to a positive value.